# Outlook VSTO: Fastening email loop on a large pst file

Tags: vb.net, outlook

In a Outlook VSTO Addin I needed to loop through a large pst file (e.g 30GB containing 50k+ mails). Following code block loop the pst file folder by folder recursively. It takes huge time (1hour+) to complete the loop especially when looping such large pst file for the first time.

The purpose of this code is to get the PR_SEARCH_KEY and the FolderPath of each email (folder wise) and store them in text file which will be used in future, such as in a periodic full loop we can compare the old and new PR_SEARCH_KEY to find out the new emails etc

**How can I get a faster performance in this.**

```
Const PropName As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x300B0102"
Dim SourceFolder = Outlook.NameSpace.Folders("Outlook_Backup")
Dim PstName = "Outlook"
Dim MailCount = FunctionToGetTotalMailCount(SourceFolder)
Dim PrSearchKeyDictionary As New List(Of String)

ScanPST(SourceFolder,PstName,MailCount)

Public Sub ScanPST(f As Outlook.Folder, PstName As String, MailCount As Long) 
'-========================================================================
'- f = RootFolder/PST with Tag (e.g Outlook_Backup), PstName (e.g Outlook)
'-========================================================================
If f.Items.Count > 0 Then
    For i = f.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        LoopCount += 1
        Try
            Dim Mail As Object = f.Items(i)             
            Dim PropertyAccessor As Outlook.PropertyAccessor = Mail.PropertyAccessor                
            Dim PrSearchKey As String = PropertyAccessor.BinaryToString(PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PropName))

            '/Full folder path splited into array and removed the rootfolder name with tag (e.g Outlook_Backup -> _Backup is the tag)
            Dim FolderPath() As String = f.FolderPath.TrimStart("\"c).Split("\").Skip(1).ToArray 

            '/Array joined back to get MailFolderPath without tag
            Dim MailFolderPath As String = String.Join("\", FolderPath) 

            PrSearchKeyDictionary.Add(PrSearchKey & "," & PstName & "\" & MailFolderPath)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(PropertyAccessor)              
        Catch ex As Exception
            LogInput("[Error: " & ex.ToString & "]"
            Continue For
        End Try
        BGWorkerStatus = "[" & PstName & "] " & "Scanning... " & Math.Round((LoopCount / MailCount) * 100, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) & "%"
        BackGroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, BGWorkerStatus)
    Next
End If  
If f.Folders.Count > 0 Then
    For c = 1 To f.Folders.Count
        OL.Folder = f.Folders.Item(c)
        ScanPST(OL.Folder, PstName, MailCount)
    Next
End If  
End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at your code I see some stuff which could speed this up if coded different.

```
'/Full folder path splited into array and removed the rootfolder name with tag (e.g Outlook_Backup -> _Backup is the tag)
Dim FolderPath() As String = f.FolderPath.TrimStart("\"c).Split("\").Skip(1).ToArray 

'/Array joined back to get MailFolderPath without tag
Dim MailFolderPath As String = String.Join("\", FolderPath)
```

For each Item in `f.Items` you are trimming the `FolderPath` and `Split` it by `\` to `Skip` the first arrayitem before you call `ToArray()`. The `ToArray()` isn't needed because [this overload](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__) of `String.Join` would take an `IEnumerable(Of String)`.

But the main point here is that `f.FolderPath` won't change for each `Item`. It would be much faster to pull this outside of the `For` loop.

Removing the `BackGroundWorker.ReportProgress()` for each and every `Item` would speed this up as well. How about reporting progress only for each folder?

---

Although VB.NET isn't case sensitive it would be good to follow the [.Net Naming Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) for naming things.

Comment: Thank You. Im going to apply your suggestion and will get back to you soon.

Comment: I've applied the modified version (included in main post) according to your suggestion. But its still taking more than an hour.

Comment: Did you compile it using release mode ?

Comment: How often did the code throw an exception?

Comment: Yes, It was in release mode and this code block doesn't usually through exceptions.

Comment: Then maybe it can't get faster with using outlook. You may check out http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the need for recursion, you could store the folders in a stack instead.

```
    Dim foldersToProcess As New Stack(Of Outlook.Folder)

    ' Add root folder

    While foldersToProcess.Count > 0
        Dim curfolder = foldersToProcess.Pop()

        ' Process folder

        ' Add child folders
        For Each childFilter In f.Folders
            foldersToProcess.Push(childFilter)
        Next
    End While
```

You might not need OL here since you put it right back

```
OL.Folder = f.Folders.Item(c)
ScanPST(OL.Folder, PstName, MailCount)
```

Your split and join could be reduce to an indexOf with a substring

```
    Dim folder = "\aaa\bbb\ccc"
    Dim newFolder = folder.Substring(folder.IndexOf("\", 2)) ' Will equal" \bbb\ccc"
```

Like Heslacher said, you don't need to ReportProgress every changes. Especially with all the math and string concatenation done for BGWorkerStatus (maybe look at string builder).

If things are the same (like PrSearchKey or MailFolderPath) for the same folder, it shouldn't be calculated multiple time.

If exceptions happen often, try to do a check that would prevent it from happening. Exceptions are slow.